# refresh modal with Chrome dev tools to view HTML/CSS changes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on the HTML and CSS of a modal that pops up with query results after submitting a zip code in a form field.  I make changes in the HTML/CSS and then refresh the page in the browser and have to enter the zip code and submit the form again to see if the changes to the modal are rendering the way I expect.  I want to just refresh the modal without having to submit the zip code every time.  Someone showed me a way to do this in Chrome dev tools once, but I can't remember how she did it.  Does this ring any bells for anyone?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything should be able to get handled through JS, you can use [DevTools Snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en). These are handy little chunks of JS that you can execute on-demand to do whatever you need in your page.

Just like a normal script, i.e:

```
// Grab the zip input and change the value.
let zipInput = document.querySelector('[name="zip"]');
zipInput.value = '90210';
// Just get the associated form to the zip and submit.
zipInput.form.submit();
```

Assuming your event is handled by eating the form's `submit` event that snippet should work (with selector/zip modification of course.) This saves you from retyping and submitting each reload, all you need to do is run the snippet.

If the HTML and CSS of the modal are generated server-side and sent to the client with each request, you could simply close the modal and re-submit. Since that would incur a new request and the contents of the modal would be re-applied.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I had been shown in the past, but I think it will do the trick.  Thanks!